# linear functional, linearly independent

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $E$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-vectorspace with basis $\mathcal{B}=\{b_i:i\in I\}$. For every $i\in I$ define a linear functional $f_i: E\to\mathbb{K}$ with $f_i(b_j):=\delta_{ij}$, where $\delta_{ij}=\begin{cases} 1, i=j\\ 0, i\neq j\end{cases}$
>
> Show , that $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ are linear indepentend

Do I have to show, that for $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{K}$ suppose $\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i f_i(b_j)=0\Rightarrow \lambda_i=0$ for every $i\in I$?

Edit:
I would proceed like this:
Since $f_i$ are linear, we have:

$\sum_{i\in I} \lambda_if_i(b_j)=\sum_{i\in I\setminus\{j\}} \lambda_if_i(b_j)=-\lambda_jf_j(b_j)=-\lambda_j$

Since $f_i(b_j)=0$ for every $i\in I\setminus\{j\}$ it is $0=-\lambda_j$.
But this can not be right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i f_i=0$, where $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{K}$.
Consider $\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i f_i(b_j)=0$. 
Then 
$$
0= \sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i f_i(b_j)= \lambda_j f_j(b_j)=\lambda_j.
$$
Since $j$ is arbitrary, $\lambda_i=0$ for each $i\in I$. 
Thus $\{ f_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a set of linearly independent functionals.

Comment: Why is $j$ arbitrary and not fixed?

Comment: Although we have shown that $\lambda_j=0$, our initial choice for $j$ is arbitrary (that is, you can repeat the entire argument for each $j$).

Comment: Does $\sum_{i\in I} \lambda_if_i=0$ mean it is $\sum_{i\in I} \lambda_if_i(w)=0$ for every $w\in E$, espacially for $b_j$, where we know, that $f_i(b_j)=0$ for $i\neq j$ and $f_i(b_j)=1$ for $i=j$. Then we conclude $\lambda_i$ has to be 0 for every $i\in I$. But why is it "legal" that we can repeat the process? I do not understand why have first a fixed $j$ and then simply repeat the process and conclude $\lambda_i=0$ for every $i\in I$.

Comment: @Cornman The answer to your first question: yes. That is why I made the small edit so that it is more clear.

Comment: @Cornman You can run the argument in the way that I have written or you can run the argument as in your comment above.

Comment: Ok, I didnt see you edited it. Thank you.